# How to show the numeric keypad

Tags: android, text, android-edittext

I read several other posts and using input.setInputType(TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL); does open the keyboard but its not the numeric keyboard

Is there a trick to this?

Answer (score 26):

give 
`android:inputType="number"` inside your xml file

Edit: "Number" does not work, changed to "number" (lowercase N)

Comment: The editview is on a popup using builder so there is no xml. I think the setInputType does the same thing as doing that in the XML

Answer (score 14):

**a) in xml**

```
android:numeric="decimal"
```

**b) in code**

```
EditText editView = new EditText(this);
editView.setKeyListener(new DigitsKeyListener());
```

Answer (score 9):

In your xml, you have to do this:

```
android:inputType="Number"
```

In your code, do:

```
editText.requestFocus();
```

Then:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

Took me many days to figure this out. I even tried editText.performClick(); Not working.

Comment: The flag InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT is the key to open the corresponding type of keyboard setted in the EditText InputType. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

To pop up a numeric keyboard on start of the activity i used following steps:

Created edit text field in **layout** as:

```
 <EditText
        ...
        android:inputType="number"    
        ...  />
```

In function **onCreate()**  show soft keyboard

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,0);
```

Most important is to give focus to edit text in **onResume** method.

```
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        editText.requestFocus();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found two easy ways to do it, add one of them to EditText block in XML file:

1. Numeric dial keyboard pad

```
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:digits="1234567890"
```

2. Numeric section of keyboard

```
        android:inputType="number"
```