# There is an alternative to <input type="number"> for display numeric keyboard on Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

`<input type="number">` has a lot of problems. For example browser does validation etc.

Comment: What are the user's entering that is not a valid number?

Comment: This has already been asked/answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4676623/how-to-show-the-numeric-keypad

Comment: @hipkiss No, that question is about native Android layout XML specification, it does not apply here (html/web).

Comment: ah i see, i misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

The only HTML alternative that will pop up a numeric keyboard in Anroid is `<input type="tel">`, and that isn't going to do you any good.

You are not being very clear about why browser validation would be a problem. In practice, it rarely is. The most obvious potential drawback would be not being able to enter a decimal separator, but that can be remedied by specifying a step size. Example:

```
<input type="number" step="any" />
```

If there are any other specific drawbacks you encountered, you should add those to your question. Focus on your actual problem, not on a specific solution.